# Grouping textbox and label together

Tags: xamarin.ios

I have a lookup view on my xamarin.iOS app where the user puts their subdomain in and I want the textbox to be to the left of the label that has the parent domain, the image below shows what I basically want to achieve:

[image: Example of expected result in iOS]

I was easily able to achieve this on android using drawables but my iOS skills are not as sharp so I'm lost on how I do this on iOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in iOS ,you can implment it in code.

> in xxxViewController

```
public override void ViewDidLoad()
 {
   base.ViewDidLoad();

   UIView backgroundView = new UIView(new CGRect(10,50,View.Bounds.Width-20,30));

   UILabel domainLab = new UILabel()
    {
      Text = " https://www.example.com ",
      Font = UIFont.SystemFontOfSize(12),
      TextColor = UIColor.Gray ,
      BackgroundColor=UIColor.LightGray,
      Frame=new CGRect(0,0,150,30)
    };

    UITextField textField = new UITextField()
    {
      Frame=new CGRect(150,0,View.Bounds.Width-170,30),
    };

    textField.Layer.MasksToBounds = true;
    textField.Layer.BorderColor = UIColor.LightGray.CGColor;
    textField.Layer.BorderWidth = (System.nfloat)0.5;

    backgroundView.AddSubview(domainLab);
    backgroundView.AddSubview(textField);

    View.AddSubview(backgroundView);

    // Perform any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
 }
```

[image]

Comment: awesome, I appreciate the help :)